# Sitecore Rocks not working properly with VS 2012 Ultimate

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I have installed VS 2012 Ultimate and Sitecore Rocks 1.4, connected to the sitecore instance, create a solution and connected with sitecore rocks and when I try to create a layout from my solution Im getting an error 
"`Could not load file or assembly sitecore.rocks, version 2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytocken="...`

I tried to installed Rocks version 2 but its not getting installed in VS 2012,
Please help me on fixing this..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I hope this will help someone in the future.

I was having the same error and then I realized the extention is local to the user. I login as a different user and install the extention and it worked for that user.

So under my user I uninstalled the extension.

Remove folder C:\Users\ *{Your Username}*\AppData\Local\Sitecore

Then searched for "rocks" in C:\Users\ *{Your Username}*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio and add remove those items too.

I don't know if I had to but I also removed these registry entries.(Remember to do a backup before removing them.)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ *{Your VS version}*\DialogPage\Sitecore.VisualStudio.Options.VisualStudioOptions

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sitecore\Sitecore.Rocks.VisualStudio

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sitecore\VisualStudio

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sitecore A/S\Sitecore Rocks

Rebooted and reinstalled the extension then everything worked.